# Dataiku gensim install problem fatal error

Tags: python, package, gensim, fatal-error, dataiku

I'm working with a python notebook in Dataiku, I used gensmin package and it worked fine till last week.

Now I've tried to pip install gensim again, and at first it seems that it loads the chached package:

'Using cached gensim-4.2.0.tar.gz'

But at the end I get a fatal error attached in the image  below.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcxD8.png)

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Unfamiliar with 'dataiku', but are you sure that their recommended way to install packages is via `pip`, from within a notebook cell like in your screenshot? Can you wipe your entire environment clean, starting fresh?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which OS are you working on? If it's Linux you have to install the development Python package, generally called `python3-dev`. Just do `apt-get install python3-dev` in the terminal and try again.

Comment: Having the `python3-dev` stuff will help if you truly need to local-compile stuff – but for most destination systems, the necessary libraries are pre-compiled into Python wheels, and if a `pip` (or other) install *previously* worked without involving local-compilation, figuring out why that stopped may be easier. (Did your notebook host change OS, or Python version, or other things since when it last worked?)

Comment: @gojomo Got an issue with that, I don't have those permissions because I don't have an admin role, but it is acceptable to use pip install. And regarding the other comment, none of that changed, so I'm not sure what could happen.

Answer (score 0):

From Dataiku support:

> Navigate to Administrations>Code Envs>Python_xxx and add gensim in
> Requested packages.
>
> If the code-environment update fails, please reach out to the admin to
> install the system package  python3-devel. ​The admin should be able
> to install this depending on the OS the DSS is installed.